# remove originally installed linux kernel, when custom one has been deployed

Tags: linux, kernel, remove

How do I remove last, the originally installed kernel?

Goal:   I am trying to configure smallest possible linux server install (Debian 9) machine which will be running application server (PHP7) in a Nginx-PHP7-Database chain.
My PHP7 app server(s) will run on blade server(s) living inside enclosure.
Machines are 32cores+8GB ram, but diskless, with os booted from 2GB (ONLY 2GB!) pendrive.

What I have done so far:

- Minimal install of `Debian 9` (took 700MB), cmdline + sshd.
- Compiled and tested custom kernel 4.9.65 for this machine, profiled to existing hardware and requirements.
- Deployed custom kernel to the machine (as `linux-image.*.deb` package)
- Successfully booted from pen-drive using custom kernel

Now I would like to remove original bloated kernel 4.9.0.4 which came with initial Debian 9 installation, which is now polluting my tiny pen-drive.
I od not need to keep last-good kernel.

When I try to remove original, now unused kernel, it wants to upgrade it (to keep dependencies happy, I presume)

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64
```

I get

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64
```

But I want to **delete** it, not upgrade.

Question:
How do I remove original, LAST standard kernel? Is there any way to re-link package dependencies to my new custom kernel and free the original for deletion?

FYI:
I cannot simply buy big pen-drives, as these are awfully slow under ext2 file system. The small ones I have are special 'enterprise' grade.

I could try some magic with generic image on iSCSI drive and overlayfs the pendrive to get personality. Not there yet, maybe in few months.

ANSWER:
I let `apt-get purge [...]` install next version of kernel, which I was able to remove without further problems.

Clean, useful minimal server on Debian9 is 465MB, all packages kept.

Comment: Please add the answer to the answer section and accept it to preserve the format of the site.

Answer (score 0):

The one of interesting things when you are working with packages is **package holding**. Hold - mark package in hold state which prevents it from changes (updates, removes).

Set hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

Remove the hold:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I let `apt-get purge [...]` install next version of kernel, which in turn I was able to remove without further problems.

Clean, useful minimal server on Debian9 is 465MB, all packages kept.

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade to the new kernel and a system reboot, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
for kernelimage in $(dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r) | awk '{print $2}'); do dpkg --purge $kernelimage; done
```